# live search using knockout produces error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am making a live search using knockout.

I have followed the example the best I could, but am getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return title }" Message: title is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var points = [
    {title: 'San Francisco Zoo',longitude: 37.7331,lattitude: -122.5031},
    {title: 'Lake Merced', longitude:37.7094,lattitude:-122.4958}
];

var viewModel = {
    query: ko.observable('')
};

viewModel.points = ko.computed(function(){
    var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(points, function(point){
        return point.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search)>=0;
    });
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<input id="s-input" class="controls" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" placeholder="Sites Search">
<ul data-bind=" template: {name:'point', foreach: points">
    <li data-bind="text: title"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's with the incomplete `template: { name: 'point'`? Seems like it should just be `data-bind="foreach: points"`.

Comment: I think templates used to be the way `foreach` was done, and a lot of people are continuing that legacy practice. The only need for templates now is if they are recursively defined.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is stating that the property `title` does not exist in the context of the line `<li data-bind="text: title"></li>`.

The syntax error here `<ul data-bind=" template: {name:'point', foreach: points">` prevents the context of the next line from being a `point` object and instead retains the original context which is the view model itself. Your view model does not have a `title` property, hence the error.